# Unable to upload SVG images to any glyph maker, but renders correctly in Inkscape

Tags: svg, fonts

I've been trying to get an Operator-similar font to be created a TTF for, but for some reason it appears to be empty whenever I try to upload it to a service.  I was able to render it in Inkscape correctly, so I don't think it would be a problem with the exact SVG image.  Here is the uppercase B, for reference (simplified):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="">
      <g i:e="1" transform="matrix(10,27.5,0,1.25,0,-168)" style="height:auto;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;width:auto;perspective-origin:0px 0px;transform:matrix(10, 27.5, 0, 1.25, 0, -168);transform-origin:0px 0px;">
       <i:p style="height:auto;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;width:auto;perspective-origin:50% 50%;transform-origin:0px 0px;"/>
       <g q:rq="0" style="height:auto;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;width:auto;perspective-origin:0px 0px;transform-origin:0px 0px;">
        <path fill="#414141" d="M3.773 86.883L4.0 81.723C3.766 80.938 3.52 80.418 3.258 80.211L2.938 87.258C2.676 99.059 2.43 110.379 2.195 121.488L2.414 116.656C2.492 113.035 2.566 109.441 2.645 105.77L3.539 86.129C3.617 86.344 3.699 86.59 3.773 86.883ZM3.078 85.84L3.105 85.207C3.234 85.43 3.359 85.652 3.48 85.957L2.703 103.063C2.828 97.375 2.953 91.605 3.078 85.84Z" style="height:auto;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;width:auto;perspective-origin:0px 0px;transform-origin:0px 0px;fill:rgb(65, 65, 65);d:path('M 3.773 86.883 L 4 81.723 C 3.766 80.938 3.52 80.418 3.258 80.211 L 2.938 87.258 C 2.676 99.059 2.43 110.379 2.195 121.488 L 2.414 116.656 C 2.492 113.035 2.566 109.441 2.645 105.77 L 3.539 86.129 C 3.617 86.344 3.699 86.59 3.773 86.883 Z M 3.078 85.84 L 3.105 85.207 C 3.234 85.43 3.359 85.652 3.48 85.957 L 2.703 103.063 C 2.828 97.375 2.953 91.605 3.078 85.84 Z');"/>
       </g>
      </g>
     </svg>
```

Could this be a problem with the way it was created?  I did try to resave it in Inkscape, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly even then.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/check, use "direct input", paste in your code. A fair few errors (I have no idea what those letter:letter attributes are, but they are definitely not part of SVG. Did you make sure to export the SVG in a clean form from inkscape instead of using inkscape's own overloaded project SVG?)

Answer (score 0):

As I tested you `SVG` it wasn't a valid code and didn't work for me, but its capital A and here's the new `SVG` below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 27.2 32.6" enable-background="new 0 0 27.2 32.6" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M7.9,22.1L4.7,32H0.5L11.2,0.6H16L26.8,32h-4.3l-3.4-9.9H7.9z M18.2,18.9l-3.1-9c-0.7-2-1.2-3.9-1.6-5.7h-0.1
  c-0.5,1.9-1,3.8-1.6,5.7l-3.1,9.1H18.2z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Try that and let me know if it works.

I added `height` and `width` but you can remove them or change the value

Comment: Yes, so it does look like it works, but it seems to be a stock sans-serif font.  Is there any validation tool that might be able to correct the font that I already have?  The code snippet does run and produce a capital A correctly, however.

Comment: What is the font name you're using? I can update the code for you. And what are you trying to do with this? just use Illustrator to make generate your `SVG` and read this about [using svg](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Comment: I was planning to create an Operator font alternative, as the original post states.  Hence, there isn't any font that exists currently, and so this is the only SVG that I have.